# jQuery - sort HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen many many posts regarding sorting, but none that answers what would seem to be a typical scenario.

I am trying to sort and HTML table using jQuery where the links I click to sort the columns don't exist within that table that is being sorted. I "fake" a table header to accommodate a scrolling table requirement.

What I do now is -

- Load an array with the values within the column that need to be
  selected along with the row id's
- Sort that array based on those value
- Insert the rows into the HTML table based on index from that sorted array.

As expected, this takes close to 10 seconds to run locally.

Code sample -

```
var sortArr = new Array();

$('tr td.' + name).each(function () {
    ResidentID = $(this).parent().attr("ResidentID");
    BID = $(this).parent().attr("BRecordID");

    if ($(this).find('select').length > 0) { //ddls
        columnText = $(this).find('select option:selected').text();
        sortArr.push({ residentId: ResidentID, bID: BID, text: columnText });
    }
    else if ($(this).find('input').length > 0) {//Textbox or checkboxes
        columnText = $(this).find('input').val();
        sortArr.push({ residentId: ResidentID, bID: BID, text: columnText });
    }
});

if (sortDirection == 'ascending') {
    colHeader.attr('sortorder', 'descending')
    sortArr = sortArr.sort(function (v, t) {
        return v.text.localeCompare(t.text);
    });
}
else {
    colHeader.attr('sortorder', 'ascending')
    sortArr = sortArr.sort(function (v, t) {
        return t.text.localeCompare(v.text);
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < sortArr.length; i++) {
    $("[id$=fixedDataTable] > tbody > tr").eq(i).after($("[id$=trFixedDataRow_" + sortArr[i].residentId + "]"));

    $("[id$=residentDetailDataTable] > tbody > tr").eq(i).after($("[id$=trResScrollDataRow_" + sortArr[i].residentId + "]"));

    $("[id$=bDetailDataTable] > tbody > tr").eq(i).after($("[id$=trBScrollDataRow_" + sortArr[i].bmrID + "]"));
}
```

Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but is there a reason you haven't used a plugin such as [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/); in particular, [sorting by column index from a link outside the table](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html) seems to do what you want

Comment: or have you tried [datatables](http://datatables.net/)? It supports sorting by columns, pagination, search and a lot of other things.

Comment: @ChrisW - I wasn't aware of tablesorter having functionality to sort based on a link outside of table.

Comment: @ChrisW - Also, I am sorting 3 tables with corresponding ids within the rows based on a click outside of any of the 3 tables. Clicking on column 3 in the first table builds a list of ordered id's that I used within the other 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of finding column to be sorted, sort it, and repopulate table is correct. But how you are doing that looks to be inefficient. Few things you can do to speed up

1. Avoid reconstructing jquery object. For example you have `$(this)` in numerous places. Cache it in a local variable.
2. Instead of directly manipulating the dom. Consider having the data in a 2D array, which directly maps out to the dom table. I think this will be the biggest improvement. You can sort the 2D array based on however you want, then just repopulate the dom table.
3. Considering giving each table row a unique-id based on its cell/row. That way the 2D array can map out more easily

   Going back to your code, for this part of the snippet

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < sortArr.length; i++) {
       $("[id$=fixedDataTable] > tbody > tr").eq(i).after($("[id$=trFixedDataRow_" +     sortArr[i].residentId + "]"));

       $("[id$=residentDetailDataTable] > tbody > tr").eq(i).after($("    [id$=trResScrollDataRow_" + sortArr[i].residentId + "]"));

       $("[id$=bDetailDataTable] > tbody > tr").eq(i).after($("[id$=trBScrollDataRow_" + sortArr[i].bmrID + "]"));
   }
   ```

can you just save the result of `$("[id$=...tr")` into a variable before the for loop so that way jquery doesn't have to look for it in every iteration? And you can probably just index the cached data yourself?

Comment: That seems like it would have worked, but it didn't as far as putting the rows into the correct index.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to this way of sorting seems to be the only approach.